# What's LLVMBlockAddress() first argument?

Tags: llvm

I'm playing a bit with LLVM C-API and I'm somehow stuck with LLVMBuildIndirectBr(), or more exactly with LLVMBlockAddress() because I have no idea what its first argument is and more importantly how can I create it. It's a LLVMValueRef wich is supposed to represent 'the function' but the documentation I found doesn't tell more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [its code](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8cpp_source.html#l01950), this function is just a C wrapper for [BlockAddress::get()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BlockAddress.html#af6e2f535824d8f9b4bf1b1a75e5ab57c). So, the first argument is the `Function` that contains the BB, I presume.

There is no C API for `BlockAddress::get()` overload taking only BB argument, so you have to call [LLVMGetBasicBlockParent()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCoreValueBasicBlock.html#ga94bcbe957389c2c2219d6a02e72691ef) on that BB first to obtain a reference to the `Function` it belongs to, and then pass it as first parameter to `LLVMBlockAddress()`.

As a rule of thumb in such situations, try to figure out "native" C++ method you are using, and then look for its documentation.

Comment: sure but the question was about creating a LLVMValueRef from this Function and looking at the C++ API doesn't help for this.

Comment: @lucvoo Well, `BlockAddress::get()` has an overload that takes only BB and finds out the `Function` it belongs to with `bb->GetParent()`. So, you can use [LLVMGetBasicBlockParent()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCoreValueBasicBlock.html#ga94bcbe957389c2c2219d6a02e72691ef), I guess.

Comment: Great, it's exactly what I was searching for! Can you edit your answer or create another for this LLVMGetBasicBlockParent()?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's via LLVMFunctionType() and LLVMAddFunction().

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    int main(int arg_count, char **args)
    {
    label0:
        if (arg_count < 2)
        {
            uint32_t addr1 = &&label1 - &&label0;
            uint32_t addr2 = &&label2 - &&label0;
            printf("label1=%d label2=%d\n", addr1, addr2);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t addr = strtol(args[1], NULL, 0);
            printf("goto address = %d\n", addr);
            void *indirect_addr = &&label0 + addr;
            goto *indirect_addr;
        }
    
    label1:
        printf("label1\n");
        return 1;
    label2:
        printf("label2\n");
        return 2;
    }
```

clang ind_br.c -emit-llvm -S

see the output

blockaddress(@main, %10) = LLVMBlockAddress

indirectbr i8* %36, [label %29, label %10, label %31, label %10, label %10] = LLVMBuildIndirectBr + LLVMAddDestination

So first argument of LLVMBuildIndirectBr is result of one of LLVMBlockAddress()